# setupProxy.js not being loaded by react-scripts

Tags: create-react-app

I have a CRA app with `react-scripts@5.0.1` and an express API backend.  Using `proxy` in `package.json` caused it to fail on startup, so I [created a `setupProxy.js`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually) per the documentation.

The docs indicate that as long as the file is named correctly, `react-scripts` will pick it up automatically.  It doesn't, and I have no idea why.  FWIW, I'm using [craco](https://craco.js.org/), but I have verified I have the same issue when using `react-scripts`.

##### Things I've tried to fix the issue

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57960629/3120446) which said I could just add `devServer` to my `craco.config.ts` file.  I've tried adding the code both as a property of the root craco config and as one of `module.exports.webpack`.

```ts
module.exports: import('craco__craco').CracoConfig = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:5000'
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

```ts
module.exports: import('craco__craco').CracoConfig = {
  webpack: {
    // @ts-ignore
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
          '/api': 'http://localhost:5000'
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

As you can see in the latter, I had to use `// @ts-ignore` to get that to compile.  Neither worked.

##### TLDR; Things I've done to confirm the file isn't being picked up at all

- Add logging to `setupProxy.js`
- Made `setupProxy.js` throw an error
- Debugged w/ VSCode

**`setupProxy.js`**

```js
require('colors');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

console.log('*****\nsetupProxy.js called\n*****'.rainbow);

module.exports = function (app) {
  console.log('*****\nSetting up proxy\n*****'.rainbow);
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://dev.spellingbeehints.app:4000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

The two `console.log` calls never happen.  I tried `console.error` just in case CRA was swallowing them, but same issue.  I've also set a breakpoint in the file and debugged to confirm the file is never hit.  `craco.config.ts` is, so I know I've set up my VSCode `launch.json` correctly.

I've also replaced my `setupProxy.js` code with `throw new Error("this ain't working ");`, and the app starts up fine.

When I `fetch()` from `/api/...` it retrieves the HTML page that runs the React app, but that's to be expected since the proxy doesn't get setup.

Just in case it's my `.env` file...

```ini
HTTPS=true
SSL_CRT_FILE=./certs/cert.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=./certs/privkey.pem
HOST=dev.example.com
```

I do have a workaround using `webpack.DefinePlugin`, but it's less than ideal.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: With a box-fresh CRA app, if I `echo 'throw new Error("fail");' > src/setupProxy.js` then `npm start` the app fails to load in the browser, whereas without that file it loads fine. So it _does_ seem to be getting picked up.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oops!  I placed `setupProxy.js` at my root rather than in `src`.  That'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a [PEBKAC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBKAC) error.  Not surprising.  I had placed `setupProxy.js` in my root dir rather than in `/src`.